# What does pooled odds ratio in DerSimonian-Laird random effects model indicate?

Tags: meta-analysis, odds-ratio

what does pooled OR of 1.10 (95% C.I. = 0.90 to 1.25) actually means?

I understand if 95% C.I contains 1 then the result is not statistically significant or there is no significant difference between two groups.

In such situation what does pooled OR indicate? How should I interpret this value of 1.10?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are asking about 1.10 in general or just in the context of 1.10 with a CI which includes unity?

Comment: I am asking in the context of 1.10 with CI which includes unity.

Answer (score 1):

There is 'no evidence of significant difference' is one way of interpreting it. Odds themselves are not easy for everyone to understand as most will think of them as risk (e.g. %). 
In the example, there is an increased odds, but it does not meet statistical significance. With more power, eventually it will reach statistical significance, but the difference may also be meaningless in terms of real life scenarios. For example, drug A vs. drug B has a difference of OR 1.02 (95% CI 1.01 to 1.03). It's statistically significant, but the odds are so close that it most likely will affect decision-making.